# How to reuse internal API calls in protractor across different pages on test?

Tags: typescript, rest, jasmine, protractor

I am currently testing an application using protractor. Currently I have 3 different web pages that I am testing. I noticed that in each of these pages I am making API calls to different APIs and saving the response values in a dictionary and using it.

I know this might be premature optimisation but I was just wondering if I could reuse these API responses across pages.

I was thinking of using the factory design pattern where I could pass in a config object defining what APIs to call and then export the value received and then use it across tests. Here is the code fragments that I have used.

```
beforeAll(async (done) => {
        let response = await apiWithPromise(constants.getMatchesUrl, 'GET');
        response = JSON.parse(response);
        matchInfo = response.matchInfo;
        let contestUrl = `${url}?m=${cricketMatchInfo[0].matchId}`;
        let contestResponse = await apiWithPromise(contestUrl, 'GET');
        contestInfo = JSON.parse(contestResponse);
        done();
});
```

I am then using the values to verify if the web elements have the API values populated in it.

P.S. We are assuming that the API is not a point of failure because we have an API testing suite that runs before the e2e suite.

I have the same duplicate lines of code in three different pages and using the same responses. Right now I just have 3 pages but soon it will increase to more pages. Is there a way I could reuse these responses across multiple pages?? Any help will be highly appreciated.